# On Button Click Does Not Fire Up The PostBackUrl Once

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

This seems to be an easy one but got stuck on it last few hours. I've a search button that fires up PostBackUrl. The issue is it only fires up when I click the search button for the second time. Here what I did:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "View Cities - CcmApp";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView(0);
            BindPager(0);

            GetCountries();
        }
    } 

 protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        City aCity = new City();
        aCity.CityName = nameTextBox.Text;

        if (nameTextBox.Text.Length == 0 && radioCityName.Checked == true)
        {
            labelMsg.Visible = true;
            labelMsg.Text = "No search term given";
        }
        else
        {
            SearchButton.PostBackUrl = GetDefaultUrl();
        }

        BindGridView(0);
        BindPager(0);
    }

 public string GetDefaultUrl()
    {
       return "SearchCity.aspx?SearchTerm=" + nameTextBox.Text;
    }
```

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="vdGroup" 
CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="SearchButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I am not sure what causes it click second time to get the url. Is there any way to get over it?

**Note:** I am expecting to get the following output in the url - 
    http://localhost:1234/UI/SearchCity.aspx?SearchTerm=a. But works only on second button click. When I click for the first time, I get this - http://localhost:1234/UI/SearchCity.aspx

Comment: have you debugged and checked? Is it assigned correctly in the backend?

Comment: No. The TextBox holds the value and it gets passed. I've debugged and it works fine. But I've no idea why it requires the second click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PostBackUrl` url on the button is only set AFTER the first PostBack. If you would set it in `Page_Load` for example you will see that it will work on the first PostBack.

If you want the `?SearchTerm=` in the url only when there is content in `nameTextBox` you could use `Response.Redirect` or accept that there is no data in `?SearchTerm=`.

Better still check on the Clientside if `nameTextBox` has text and prevent the button click using a Validator.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="/Default.aspx?SearchTerm=" ValidationGroup="mySearch">Search</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="nameTextBox" ClientValidationFunction="checkLength" ValidateEmptyText="true" ErrorMessage="Min. 3 characters required" ValidationGroup="mySearch"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkLength(oSrc, args) {
        var v = document.getElementById("<%=nameTextBox.ClientID %>").value;
        if (v.length < 3) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>").attr("onclick", $("#<%=LinkButton1.ClientID %>").attr("onclick").replace("?SearchTerm=", "?SearchTerm=" + v));
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I initially preferred the Response.Redirect(). But it refreshes the full page and erases the value in the TextBox. Now I got it why it doesn't work on the first button click. But could I make the PostBackUrl to work in any way on the first click and not interested to use JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: But you still won't get the part after the '=' sign in the first PostBack without some sort of javascript trick. See my updated answer.

Comment: OK. I'll get on this and try using JavaScript.